How to get Godot to see/change where a dlopen() call is looking for a file?
Kind of a similar problem to my last post. Still using Godot 4.2.2 Godot mono on Mac.
I gave up on trying to use the facepunch wrapper and decided to go to GodotSteam and Steam Multiplayer peer via SeaKrill's implementation to see if I could get a starting point. However, I get these three errors when I try to run the project:
Can't open dynamic library: /Users/---/Desktop/MyGames/GodotSteam-Lobby-main/addons/steam-multiplayer-peer/osx/steam-multiplayer-peer.macos.template_debug.framework. Error: dlopen(/Applications/Godot_mono 4.2.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/steam-multiplayer-peer.macos.template_debug.framework, 0x0002): tried: '/Applications/Godot_mono 4.2.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/steam-multiplayer-peer.macos.template_debug.framework' (no such file).
core/extension/gdextension.cpp:719 - GDExtension dynamic library not found: /Users/---/Desktop/MyGames/GodotSteam-Lobby-main/addons/steam-multiplayer-peer/osx/steam-multiplayer-peer.macos.template_debug.framework
Failed loading resource: res://addons/steam-multiplayer-peer/steam-multiplayer-peer.gdextension. Make sure resources have been imported by opening the project in the editor at least once.
Again, I believe these errors are triggered because dlopen is trying to go into Godot's contents folder to find the steam-multiplayer-peer.macos.template_debug.framework file and I have no idea how to get it to look for the correct file path.
I  tried to put the debug framework file roughly where dlopen() looks by creating a Frameworks file at /Applications/Godot_mono 4.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Frameworks and placed the file in there. The problem is, I have no idea what files the .. is accessing in '/Applications/Godot_mono 4.2.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/steam-multiplayer-peer.macos.template_debug.framework' so that patch fix didn't work.
If anyone could help me figure out how to get this dlopen() call to change the path it's looking for the file for or let me know where I can see the complete file route it is trying to access so I can put the debug file in there, I would appreciate the help again.
